# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt5n!}\left(-\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(i+\bar\phi)+\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(i+\phi)\right)$

Tags: limits

Let $\phi:=(1+\sqrt5)/2,\bar\phi:=(1-\sqrt5)/2$ as the root of $X^2-X-1=0$.
We want to know the asymptotic form of 
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt5n!}\left(-\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(i+\bar\phi)+\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(i+\phi)\right).
\end{align}$$
$\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(i+\bar\phi)$is almost equal to $\Gamma(n+\bar\phi)$. So I expect we can apply the Stirling's formula, $\Gamma(z)=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{z}}\left(\frac{z}{e}\right)^e(1+O(1/z))$. However, I dont't know how to deal the error term arising from the fact that $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(i+\bar\phi)$ is not exactly equal to $\Gamma(n+\bar\phi)$. Do you have any idea to calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will change the names of the variables to fit with my usual notations, so i will not type some $n$ instead of $i$, since when i would correct, typing $i$ would hurt a little.

I will write $a$ for $\phi-1$.

We fix some big $N$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned} 
\frac 1{N!}\prod_{0\le n<N}\left(n+\phi\right)
&=
\frac 1{N!}\prod_{1\le n\le N}\left(n+a\right)
=
\prod_{1\le n\le N}\frac 1n\left(n+a\right)
=
\prod_{1\le n\le N}\left(1+\frac an\right)
\\
&\ge 1+\sum_{1\le n\le N}\frac an
\end{aligned} 
$$
and the last expression goes to infinity. Doing the same with the other product, we would introduce $b= \bar\phi-1$ which is negative, so most (all but some first) factors are between zero and one, so the second product goes to zero.

The limit in the OP is thus infinity.

Comment: Can you get the constant term by dividing everything by some function $f(N)$?