# $\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N^aN!}\prod_{i=1}^N(a+i)$

Tags: limits

Suppose $a:=(1+\sqrt5)/2$. 
 I want to know the value of $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N^aN!}\prod_{i=1}^N(a+i).$$ I previously thought $\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N!}\prod_{i=1}^N(a+i)$ goes to some constant value from the Stirling's approximation, but it is not true according to this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3454359/lim-n-to-infty-frac1-sqrt5n-left-prod-i-0n-1i-bar-phi-prod/3454502#3454502). Thus, I've been keeping looking for the asymptoic form.
By taking $\log(x)$ and approximating it by integration,
$$\begin{align}-a\log(N)+\int_1^N \log\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)dx
&=a \log(a/N + 1) + \log((a/N+1)^N) + O(1)\\
&\to O(1) \text{     (as $N\to\infty$)}\\
\end{align}$$,
we get constant term. Thus, I expect $\frac{1}{N!N^a}\prod_{i=1}^N(a+i)$ converges to some constant value, but I have no idea how to get that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gautschi's Inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/98348), which follows from the log-convexity of the Gamma function, says that
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^an!}\prod_{i=1}^n(a+i)
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^a\Gamma(n+1)}\frac{\Gamma(n+a+1)}{\Gamma(a+1)}\\
&=\frac1{\Gamma(a+1)}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+a+1)}{n^a\Gamma(n+1)}\\
&=\frac1{\Gamma(a+1)}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: If $a=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2=\phi$, the [Golden Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio), then $$\frac1{\Gamma(a+1)}\doteq0.690021787$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$\frac{1}{N^a N!}\prod_{i=1}^{N} (a+i) = \frac{1}{N^{a}\Gamma(N+1)}\frac{\Gamma(N+a+1)}{\Gamma(a+1)}.$$
We can now the following Stirling approximations:
$$\log \Gamma(z) = (z-\frac12)\ln (z)-z+\frac12\ln(2\pi)+\mathcal{O}(1/z),$$
to get
$$\log\frac{\Gamma(N+a+1)}{N^{a}\Gamma(N+1)}=a\log\frac{N+a+1}{N}+(N+\frac12)\log\frac{N+a+1}{N+1}-a+\mathcal{O}(1/N).$$
which is zero in the limit. Hence the required expression has $\frac1{\Gamma(a+1)}$ as a limit.